# Hide button in collection view once pressed

Tags: arrays, xcode, function, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that contains a button. Once the button is pressed I would like to hide it. How do I access the properties of this button in the button's function?

Thanks

```
cell.addButton.addTarget(self, action: "addToArray:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

//This is the function

```
func addToArray(sender:AnyObject) {
    println("Add to array")
}
```

Comment: The sender is the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
func addToArray(sender: UIButton) {
    println("Add to array")
    sender.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: If this answers you question you might check the answer as the correct one.

Comment: Yes. Will do. I am being asked to wait for 5 minutes.